# Do not render element if there is no data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angular ng-hide directive to hide some markup if there is no data to show:

```
<li class="header" ng-hide = " todayRecents.length === 0 ">today</li>
```

now all ng-hide does is put display value of none to the element `display:none`

What I would like it to do is not render the markup at all, is this at all possible?

Comment: It is possible, but it's usually not friendly.  Why exactly do you want to remove it from the dom altogether?

Comment: You can use ng-include for dirrefent partials. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude But that's bad idea for 1 line html code

Comment: ng-switch will also do this. The branches of the switch that are not selected are omitted, not hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Angular 1.1.5 you can use the [ngIf directive](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angIf) which removes the element from the dom, if the given expression is falsy.